# How to fix errors during the building snowball tool from sources?

Tags: installation, makefile, gnu-make, ubuntu-22.04, snowball

I've downloaded sources of https://github.com/snowballstem/snowball and try to build it by official [guide](https://snowballstem.org/runtime/use.html) on my machine.

Unfortunately, I have gotten an error

> make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

Steps to reproduce:

```bash
$ git clone https://github.com/snowballstem/snowball.git
...
Resolving deltas: 100% (3092/3092), done.
```

```bash
$ make
libstemmer/mkalgorithms.pl algorithms.mk libstemmer/modules.txt
cc -O2 -W -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations   -c -o compiler/space.o compiler/space.c
...
```

```bash
$ sudo make install
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Also I've created an issue here https://github.com/snowballstem/snowball/issues/170

I expect that all instructions from the Snowball guide should work well.

Comment: What makes you think that you should run `make install`?  I don't see any instructions to that effect in the GitHub site and certainly, just as make reports, the `GNUmakefile` doesn't define an `install` rule.

Comment: There is item `sudo make install` in this guide https://snowballstem.org/runtime/use.html  screenshot https://i.imgur.com/MUqn4ri.png

Comment: Well there's no `install` rule that I can find in the makefile, so filing an issue on the GitHub site is the correct move.  There's no point in asking on SO: this is either a bug in the makefile of that project or a bug in the documentation of that project.

Comment: So, in this case, need to close this question and continue the discussion on the GitHub issue?

Comment: That would be my recommendation.

Comment: Yeah, added extra info and closed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>OP's solution migrated from the question to an answer:</sup>

> After digging deeper, found that running `make` is enough, and it works well:
>
> ```bash
> echo "running" | ./stemwords -l en
> run
> ```

Also guide was updated https://snowballstem.org/runtime/use.html